# Passing an attribute name as an argument in a method not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, helper

I'm trying to define a method in a model to simplify things I'm doing in my controller as below:

**models/game.rb**

```
def build_array_for(words)
  words.downcase.split(",")
end
```

I'm calling the method in the controller as below

**games_controller.rb**

```
@wordsArray = @game.build_array_for(red_words)
```

Note that 'red_words' is an attribute of instances of Game which value is supposed to be a string

When I call the method I get:

> undefined local variable or method `red_words' for GamesController

If I build the method as:

```
def build_array
  red_words.downcase.split(",")
end
```

it works but since I'm using it with other attributes for the same purpose it wouldn't make sense.

What am I missing here, could it be that the argument is passed as a string and for some reason the name of the attribute is not recognised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need build array for existed column then you can try this:

```
def build_array_for(column)
  self[column].downcase.split(",")
end
```

If you want build array for any instance variable when:

```
def build_array_for(name)
  self.send(name).downcase.split(",")
end
```

Use symbol or string for a parameter:

```
@wordsArray = @game.build_array_for(:red_words)
```

Comment: No luck Alex, both alternatives derive in the same error

Comment: Call it like this `@wordsArray = @game.build_array_for(:red_words)`

Comment: That's great Alex it works great now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to

```
def build_array_for(words)
  words.downcase.split(",")
end
```

When you are using `self` rails will try to find an attribute `words` or instance method `words` for `Game` object

**EDIT**

Make this changes accordingly

**games_controller.rb**

```
@wordsArray = @game.build_array_for(red_words)
```

**models/game.rb**

```
def build_array(red_words)
  red_words.downcase.split(",")
end
```

Comment: The result is the same. I think in Ruby it's the same using 'self' or not? In both cases is trying to find an instance method that takes the value of the parameter 'words' for the Game object. 
In both cases I get "undefined local variable or method `red_words' "

Comment: If its not an `attribute` or an `association` you must pass it as parameter

Comment: make sure you are passing the params with method call and accepting the params in method

Comment: Yes, I tried without 'self' as your code above before. However, I'm getting the same error (I'll take out 'self' from question to not confuse).

Comment: Not sure that I follow your train of thought.
'red_words' is definitely an attribute of instances of Game, if I call @game.red_words it all works fine.